# background won't cover content

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have the white background cover content of the page but for some reason it only ends at the navigation menu/#main_content_top. How can I fix this?

HTML Look/Image:
http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/8461/croppercapture12.th.jpg

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #Text1
        {
            width: 77px;
        }
        #Text2
        {
            width: 78px;
        }
    body {
}
    </style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header"><h1>  
    <img alt="" src="images/tempBanner.jpg" style="width: 747px; height: 75px" /></h1></div>

<div id="sub_header">Facility Booking Registration</div>

<div id="main_content_top"><a href ="Home.htm">Home</a> | <a href = "BookFacility.htm">Book a Facility</a> | <a href ="FindBooking.htm" >Find/Delete a 
    booking</a></div>

<div id="main_content">

<div class="content">

<p class="title">Public Service Announcements</p>
<h2>Vesak Day</h2>
<p>Vesak Day, a public holiday, will fall on 1/5/2011, please note the school will 
    be closed and no bookings will be allowed on this day.</p>
<h2>Labour Day</h2>
<p>Labour Day, a public holiday, will fall on 1/5/2011, please note the school will 
    be closed and no bookings will be allowed on this day.</p>
</div>

<div class="menu">
<div class="menu_title">Login</div>
<div>Username:
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <br />
    Password:
    <input id="Text2" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Sign In" />
                </div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="clear"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS style sheet:

```
body {
    background: #CACACA url(images/background.png) repeat-x;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, serif, Arial
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
}
#sub_header {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#main_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF url('images/background_content.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
} 
#main_content_top {
    height: 30px;
    background: #FFFFFF url('images/background_top.gif');

} 
#main_content_bottom {
    height: 30px;
    background: #FFFFFF url('images/background_bottom.gif');
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 510px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    font-size: 14px
}
.menu {
    width: 139px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-left: #8C8484 1px solid;
    font-size: 12px
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px
}
.menu il {
    list-style-type: disc
}
#header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #A40008
}
.content h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #A40008
}
.menu_title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold
}
#clear {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a {
    color: #A40008;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none
}
a:hover {
    color: #A40008;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline
}
.title {
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 18px;
}
.highlight 
{
    font-weight:bold
}
.update
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:Green
}

.confirm
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:Red
}

table
{
    border-style : dashed
}
```

Comment: the img you provide is way too tiny to understand what you're referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding overflow:auto to #main_content.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to set the background of the body white? If that is your requirement, within the body CSS, remove or comment out the background style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it overflow hidden or float left and width..........